# Proxmox - Configure two bridges in a single NIC

Tags: linux, networking, debian, network-interface, proxmox

I have Proxmox installed in two servers directly linked by a switch, I need to configure two different addresses in a specific NIC (that have a capacity of 10GB) for each server.

I tried many solutions found on the internet but the best result I got is being able to ping only one address.

here are some of the solutions I tried:

1.

```
iface eno1np0 inet manual
iface eno1np0.4 inet manual

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 10.20.2.5/24
        bridge-ports eno1np0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

auto vmbr2
iface vmbr2 inet static
        address 10.20.4.5/24
        bridge-ports eno1np0.4
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
```

2. 

```
auto eno1np0
iface eno1np0 inet static
        address 10.20.2.5/24
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eno1np0/proxy_arp

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 10.20.4.5/24
        bridge-ports eno1np0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
```

3. 

```
auto eno1np0
iface eno1np0 inet manual
       address 10.20.2.5/24

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 10.20.4.5/24
        bridge-ports eno1np0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
```

Comment: Ever heard of VLANs?

Comment: how can I set a VLAN in proxmox?

Comment: You usually set the virtual interfaces in the host OS. Both NICs need to support **802.1q**.